# How to add exporting date and time as user format in Highcharts exporter?

Tags: highcharts

I am developing an application using `Primefaces 6.0`, `JSF 2.2` and `Highcharts v3.0.7`.

In that, I need to include an exporting date, time and user name on the bottom of the document while PDF exporting and printing the `Highcharts` chart.

**My sample chart:**

[image]

**Expecting this format while export and print the chart:**
[image]

Help me to add the format in `Highcharts` exporters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a 'Generated on' field you can use credits. There is an object where you can set all options that you want to apply on export. It is called `exporting.chartOptions`. There, you can set load event where credits' text will be updated with current data. As for the 'Generated by' field, you need to modify Chart.getSVG() function (more about wrapping a function can be found below, in DOCS Reference section) to add additional text to chart SVG, as you cannot have two credits. Look at the demo I have prepared for you.

DOCS Reference:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/credits
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/w71cp4ha/